# Background-image on every side visible

Tags: css, background-image

I´ve the following background image with content inside of it: [Image](http://wowimg.zamimg.com/images/wow/tooltip.png)

I want that the border is always visible on every side.

```
.itembox {
  background: url(http://wowimg.zamimg.com/images/wow/tooltip.png);
  font-family: Verdana,"Open Sans",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 8px;
```

I tried this:

```
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
html,body {
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

update:

In your `.itembox` css, I added only this:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

(and no `background-repeat`) which seems to work for me.

I'm curious though, if you really want to use that specific image as a background, wouldn't it be easier to just define a `background-color` with a `border` and a `border-radius`? If you stretch the image like you do, the border doesn't really look all that good...

Comment: I tried, but now no border is visible anymore.

Comment: Can you edit your question to display your full html and css code then? Otherwise I'm just guessing for answers...

Comment: Ok i posted my css code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated my answer. Hope it's useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason:**

The white line you see around the image will become increasingly clearer show as you increase the size of your div that has the image. As  your div that contains the image get smaller, you will notice that thing line disappears because the **smallest unit** of measurement is

```
                               `1 pixel`
```

Anything smaller than that will not display in the browser

this is a snapshot where you see the white line

```css
body{
  background:blue;
}
.itembox {
  background-image: url("http://wowimg.zamimg.com/images/wow/tooltip.png");
  font-family: Verdana,"Open Sans",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  height:1000px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
   }
```

```html
<div class="itembox">
Something<br>
Something<br>
Something<br>
Something<br>
</div>
```

this is a snapshot where the broswer failed to show that white line because of the relative size of that line compare to the size of the div

```css
body{
  background:blue;
}
.itembox {
  background-image: url("http://wowimg.zamimg.com/images/wow/tooltip.png");
  font-family: Verdana,"Open Sans",Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 17px;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  height:100px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  
   }
```

```html
<div class="itembox">
Something<br>
Something<br>
Something<br>
Something<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!